# React + Google Maps JS API, dynamically render markers from state

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

In React, I'm trying to populate my google map with markers where each marker is determined by an array of objects in my state. Right now, if I have a reducedSites array of say 22 objects, only 1-3 of them will render as markers. This seems to be the case no matter how many objects are in state.

## Updated

```
renderMap() {
    const map = document.querySelector('#map')
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(map, {
      center: { lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
      zoom: 8
    });
    const _this = this
    let markers = this.state.reducedSites.map(function(site) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: parseInt(site.latitude), lng: parseInt(site.longitude)},
        map: _this.map
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where you are returning `new google.maps.Marker` the MarkerOptions property should be `map` and not `setMap` ie. `map: map`. This will already plot the marker on the map. So what is `marker.setMap(map)` supposed to do in your code?

Comment: I did just that and still no more than 1-3 markers will show despite the state containing upwards of 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `<Marker></Marker>` component as a child of Map and use your array to set the position property.

```
  <Map google={this.props.google}
        style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}
        className={'map'}
        zoom={14}>
      <Marker
        name={'SOMA'}
        position={{lat: this.state.markersArray[0].lat, lng: this.state.markersArray[0].lng}} />
     </Marker> 
    </Map>
```

Make sure to call setState() when changing the values of your positions array so that React automatically renders the DOM each time a value is changed. This is how you get it to render dynamically.

https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

Comment: I'm not sure how I would integrate that as I am not using this react component, just the raw google api.

Comment: It will probably make your life easier, just npm install --save google-maps-react and then at the top of your file import Map from 'google-maps-react'. But what exactly was your problem with your existing code?

Comment: It's not rendering any of the markers. If I call `setMap: map` I get an error when iterating over markers with forEach that reads `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`. If however I remove the forEach iteration, there are no errors but still no rendered markers.

Comment: I'd much rather learn how to integrate google maps without the pre configured component.

Comment: Oh! It's because you do setMap(map) and map refers to the element. I think you mean setMap(this.map). and also where you return google.maps.Marker({ setMap:this.map})

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: marker.setMap is not a function`

Comment: Check that this.map is of type google.maps.Map and that markers[0] is of type google.maps.Marker. Like this. console.log(typeof this.map) and conosole.log(typeof markers[0])

Comment: this.map is a google.maps.Map object and marker is a google.maps.Marker object.

Comment: replace setMap with map in definition of marker. Also if you do this, you shouldn't have to seperately call setMap().                                                                   new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map:map,